# Visio Shape Text positioning below the shape using Text Transform

Tags: text, position, shapes, visio, shapesheet

I have a building a set of stencil shapes and I need the text to display below the shape. I am using custom formulas to generate the text, and as such the volume of text changes from use case to use case.

What I have come across is using the Text Transform set of properties, and I have tried the following with success for a single line of text:

```
TxtWidth = TEXTWIDTH(TheText)
TxtPinX = Width * 0.5
TxtLocPinX = TxtWidth * 0.5
TxtHeight = Height * 0
TxtPinY = Height * -0.2
TxtLocPinY = TxtHieght * 0.5
TxtAngle = 0 deg
```

The problem arises when there is more than a single line of text to display -> the text appears 'half above (inside) and half below' the bottom the shape.

I would like to place all the text, regardless of how many lines there are, underneath the shape.

What I have tried is to set the TxtPinY = some formula different from above eg/ Height * -(TxtHeight). This seems to always result in an 'error in formula'.

I am sure that this is something simple that I am missing, but I cannot figure it out.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Cheers and thanks for taking a look at this,

The Frog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [`TEXTHEIGHT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/textheight-function) function to get around this. Specify a reasonable maximum text widht as a second parameter for it:

```
TxtHeight = TEXTHEIGHT(TheText,100)
TxtPinY = 0
TxtLocPinY = TxtHeight
```

Comment: Bang on! Something so simple. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code provided with the stencil available in this post:
http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=7461.msg31490#msg31490